# Package ifluatex Error

Tags: beamer, errors, miktex-update

I am new with LaTeX. I was trying to prepare a presentation with `beamer` package. However, the error that

```
Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined
```

appears whenever I try to run. Btw, on my computer at work even though I use the same file, there is no such a problem. I saw that I may need to update the MiKTeX Console both as a user and an admin, which I did. The problem still remains. Also, I realize that under the packages `ifluatex` does not appear. I figured if I manage to install that package there manually, I may solve the problem. I would be more than glad if you can help me.

Comment: you have not updated. That error only comes from the old version of the package. If you showed a small test file that makes the error and the log file someone would show you where the old luatex.sty is installed on your system. (you need to update the `iftex` package (the latex iflluatex package  is distributed as part of iftex, not as a separate miktex installation package)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to update iftex package in the miktex console. But it did not work.  I am not sure what did you mean by test file, but this is what appears at the bottom when I hit the execute button: 

"Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined. }
pdflatex.exe (file ./IV_6.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.6>, but at most version <1.5> allowed<IV_6.pdf, id=295, 397.485pt x 289.08pt>File: IV_6.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)<use IV_6.pdf>Package pdftex.def Info: IV_6.pdf used"

Comment: That just means you have the old copy of  ifluatex package installed which you should not have. By a test file I mean a small complete document that gives that error and show the full lo file that you get

Answer (score 1):

In TeX Live, you can update to the newest version of `ifluatex`m by running `tlmgr` with the command `install --reinstall iftex`.  If you have an older version of `ifluatex`, you might want to uninstall it manually, or run `update --self --all`.

You need to run it as whatever account owns your TeX tree.  Since I installed as a system account named `tex`, the command I would use is:

```
sudo -u tex $(which tlmgr) install --reinstall iftex
```

For new code, the package `iftex` replaces `ifluatex` and its brethren.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, and I simply went to the file directory where ifluatex.sty was located, renamed it as ifuatex_copy.sty (or anything else will suffice I suppose), uninstalled the iftex package from the MikTex console, then reinstalled it. Running smoothly now!

Comment: I updated MiKTex 2.9 today (Jan. 20, 2020) and then I received the error message mentioned above:
The solution by lascooter worked perfectly. Thanks!