# beamer error for .sty file

Tags: beamer, packages

I am trying to make a beamer presentation but an external error that I don't know comes up in the name `pdftexcmds.sty`. This error comes even for starting a quick beamer from wizard. This error is not from the program but a package or LaTeX error. This is the error I got :

> C:\Users\mkluw\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty : Undefined control sequence.....

When I click the error it shows a different program .sty file with the name `pdftexcmds.sty` and I cannot also run this .sty file.

log file of the error part:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 186, version
`2019/11/07' of package iftex,
but only version
`2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
and LuaTeX'
is available.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.189 \ifluatex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Extra \else.
l.190 \else
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
! Extra \fi.
l.271 \fi
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.272 \ifluatex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.273 \ifnum\luatexversion
<36 %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
<
l.273 \ifnum\luatexversion<
36 %
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Undefined control sequence.
\pdftexcmds@directlua ->\directlua
0
l.281 \pdftexcmds@directlua
{%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.281 \pdftexcmds@directlua
{%
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Extra \fi.
l.291 \fi
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.316 \ifluatex
\else
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Extra \else.
l.316 \ifluatex\else
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
! Extra \fi.
l.340 \fi
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.421 \ifluatex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Extra \else.
l.425 \else
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
! Extra \fi.
l.427 \fi
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.485 \ifluatex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Extra \else.
l.486 \else
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
! Extra \fi.
l.488 \fi
%
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdfescape.sty"
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\hycolor.sty"
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\xcolor-patch.sty"
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\hopatch.sty"
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\letltxmacro.sty"
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen165
\Hy@linkcounter=\count122
\Hy@pagecounter=\count123
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2019/06/12 v6.88h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\intcalc.sty"
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count124
Overfull \hbox (22.475pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 0
[]
Overfull \hbox (6.38751pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 if
[]
Overfull \hbox (95.9039pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 tex.enableprimitives
[]
Overfull \hbox (230.98454pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 then
tex.enableprimitives(
'pdf@',
'primitive',
[]
Overfull \hbox (13.07918pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 'if-
[]
Overfull \hbox (26.18878pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 prim-
[]
Overfull \hbox (6.69167pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 i-
[]
Overfull \hbox (23.72504pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 tive',
[]
Overfull \hbox (22.50836pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 'pdf-
[]
Overfull \hbox (27.10129pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 draft-
[]
Overfull \hbox (216.08034pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 mode','draftmode'
)
tex.enableprimitives('',
[]
Overfull \hbox (15.81668pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 'lu-
[]
Overfull \hbox (103.87305pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 281--2643
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 aescapestring')
end
[]
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4424.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `true' on input line 4424.
Package hyperref Info: Option `implicit' set `false' on input line 4424.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4550.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4555.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4558.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4565.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4570.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode OFF; no redefinition of LaTeX internals.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4803.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count125
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5156.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen166
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\bitset.sty"
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\bigintcalc.sty"
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count126
\Field@Width=\dimen167
\Fld@charsize=\dimen168
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6411.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6416.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6419.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6426.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6431.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6436.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6441.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6481.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6485.
\Hy@abspage=\count127
Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2019/06/12 v6.88h Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\atveryend.sty"
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
)
\Fld@listcount=\count128
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count129
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\uniquecounter.sty"
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaserequires.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasecompatibility.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasefont.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks26
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font) U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
```

before this,the log files are :

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count113
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count114
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by`cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by`rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model`HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model`Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model`tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model`HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model`Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model`wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen140
\pgfmath@count=\count115
\pgfmath@box=\box37
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count116
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen141
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen142
\pgf@picminy=\dimen143
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen144
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen145
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen146
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen147
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen148
\pgf@xx=\dimen149
\pgf@xy=\dimen150
\pgf@yx=\dimen151
\pgf@yy=\dimen152
\pgf@zx=\dimen153
\pgf@zy=\dimen154
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen155
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen156
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen157
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen158
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfpic=\box38
\pgf@hbox=\box39
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box40
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count117
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen159
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen160
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen161
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen162
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen163
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@max=\dimen164
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count118
\pgf@shadingcount=\count119
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box41
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex"
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\xxcolor.sty"
Package: xxcolor 2003/10/24 ver 0.1
\XC@nummixins=\count120
\XC@countmixins=\count121
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2019/06/12 v6.88h Hypertext links for LaTeX
(C:\Users\mkluw\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/hobsub\hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2019-11-14
hobsub not currently supported, see hobsub.dtx to extract original code
(C:\Users\mkluw\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
and LuaTeX
)

Updated new error after if(tex) is updated ;

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
! Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined.
See the ifluatex package documentation for explanation.
Type H  for immediate help.
...
l.174 }
%
Incompatible versions of \ifluatex can cause problems,
therefore package loading is aborted.
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

Comment: I think i got this error when I keep my laptop online. And after i updated using miktex consol

Comment: make sure that you update in user and admin mode.

Comment: yes i did that. wait, both in user and admin mode ?

Comment: And if i manually go in \AppData\Roaming\Miktex folder and delete the new updated files and replace it by the old ones, there is no error until i keep my laptop offline. If i connect to internet while running, the error comes up and same data are found in \AppData

Comment: don't delete manually files unless you know what you are doing. Show a small, complete example that demonstrates the error and can be used for a test. Show also the log-file.

Comment: As you can see that this error is for line 186 ! where i am running a simple  beamer from wizard with one frame. This error is not for the .tex file. it is coming for the .sty file running in the background.

Comment: i think the iftex package is used in the pdftexcmds.sty program and it is not available now. But i don't see any solution

Comment: you have an outdated iftex package in your path.

Comment: so do you want me to update the iftex package ? i will try that

Comment: Show a few lines of the log before the part you copied

Comment: have you seen it ?

Comment: okay, the iftex error is gone now after i update the iftex packageof 2019 version. only the ifluatex error is there.

Comment: your hyperref version is too old - I have 2020/01/14 v7.00d - this means that you didn't correctly updated. Run the miktex console in user **and** admin mode.

Comment: okay thanks a lot. i think the consol update was not completed. I will try and confirm tomorrow. I am getting some ideas now. thank u Ulrike !

Comment: Thanks all ! My problem with ifluatex is solved after i checked this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520341/207788

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved !!!!  Thanks stackExchange.

Reason for the pdftexcmds.sty error was oudated or missing pdftexcmds packages. I went to console, searched and installed or updated the packages whichever necessary. The main package was iftex package and pdftexcmds packages.

For the ifluatex error, i did exactly what was given in the answer of [Package ifluatex Error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520341/207788) and it solved ! Now, everything is working smoothly.

p.s. : If anyone get error while updating in console, like connection timeout or whatever, just change the connection setting and choose one of the countries working with you instead of random depository. I chose uk, china.